# How to find if special character occurs prior to another first special character in bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix

Say I have these lines in my file

```
file.txt

8_64056_14^8008286229^hgdggdj^33gg.gggF-gghggt.file.gz
8_64056_414^80082ww8^ghdg^hhjj.gg-ghhthh.file.gz
8_64058-4^80082862dddd9^gggj^34433-gg.file.gz
```

I need to find lines where I have `-` prior to first `^`. Based on this condition, I should match the third line `8_64058-4^80082862dddd9^gggj^34433-gg.file.gz`. How do I find this in unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to select lines with  "`-` prior to first `^`."

#### Using awk

Try:

```
$ awk -F^ '$1 ~ /-/' file
8_64058-4^80082862dddd9^gggj^34433-gg.file.gz
```

`awk` reads its input one line at a time and divides each line into fields.  `-F^` tells awk to use `^` as the field divider.  Thus, if `-` occurs in the first field, `$1`, then `-` occurs before the first `^`.

The above will return lines that contain `-` even if they don't contain `^`.  If you want to exclude that case, then use:

```
awk -F^ 'NF >= 2 && $1 ~ /-/' file
```

`NF` is the number of fields.  `NF >= 2` means that at least one `^` appeared on the line.

#### Using grep

To select all lines that contain `-` with no preceding `^`, try:

```
$ grep '^[^^]*-' file
8_64058-4^80082862dddd9^gggj^34433-gg.file.gz
```

If you want to require that a `^` follows the `-`, then:

```
grep '^[^^]*-.*^' file
```

`^[^^]` might look a little complicated.  It isn't.  The first `^` requires the match to start at the beginning of the line.  The first `^` inside the square brackets negates the match.  Thus `[^a]` matches anything except `a` and, in our case, `[^^]` matches anything except `^`.

#### Using sed

Using the same logic as for grep, try:

```
$ sed -n '/^[^^]*-/p' file
8_64058-4^80082862dddd9^gggj^34433-gg.file.gz
```

And, again, if you want to require that a `^` follows the `-`, then:

```
sed -n '/^[^^]*-.*^/p' file
```

Here, `-n` tells sed not to print a line unless we explicitly ask it to.  `/^[^^]*-.*^/p` tells it to print lines that match the regex `^[^^]*-.*^`

Answer (score 1):

Just using bash

```
cat file | while read -r line; do 
    if [[ "${line%%^*}" = *-* ]]; then
        echo "$line";
    fi
done
```

`${line%%^*}` gets the beginning of the string `$line` before the first `^`

For the 3 example strings, we got:

- `8_64056_14`
- `8_64056_414`
- `8_64058-4`

Then let's just find `-`.

```
[[ "${line%%^*}" = *-* ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

REGEX is probably the best option. `.*-.*\^` will look for anything, a dash, anything more, and then a ^.

If you read those lines in then you can do a simple check to see if the string matches the regex `[[ line =~ .*-.*\^ ]] && echo "yes"`

Comment: I'd suggest `[^]` instead of `\^`, as it works more consistently across quoting contexts. You can copy-and-paste `.*-.*[^]` into a string in a JSON document or anywhere else and be assured it'll be parsed the same way it was originally, without the backslash being consumed during an unescaping phase.